# Eureka Behind Proxy

Tags: proxy, spring-boot, spring-cloud, microservices, netflix-eureka

I have the following situation: I try to run two instances of Eureka Server which will run behind a proxy and will have to communicate through it. Their public URLs will be something like `https://<app>-serverdomain.com/<app>-<version>`. The parameters for `<app>` and `<version>` are auto-generated and can not be affected. The Proxy maps Port 443 (for HTTPS) to the port of the Eureka Server (e.g. 8761), which is auto-discovered. The application itself is obviously not aware of the context path.

When I configure Eureka I get in trouble to provide relevant Information to communicate to other peers properly on the one hand and also register an Eureka Instance. The following configuration is an example of what I tried:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: <app>-serverdomain.com
    healthCheckUrlPath: /<app>-<version>/health
    statusPageUrlPath: /<app>-<version>/info
    nonSecurePortEnabled: false
    securePortEnabled: true
    securePort: 443
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: https://<URL OF THE OTHER EUREKA>/eureka/
```

Now to the problem: Eureka is not able to handle context-paths / proxy paths properly. It will assume URLs like `https://<URL OF THE OTHER EUREKA>/eureka/:443` or just `https://<URL OF THE OTHER EUREKA>:443`, which obviously is wrong.

Is there any chance of having a method to handle this or even somebody, who already faced this circumstance?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Benjamin

Comment: Why are you putting the `/<app>-<version>` in the hostname? Surely that is part of the serviceUrl?

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. Where is the `:443` coming from at the end of the URL path?

Comment: I think eureka sets it somehow, at least spring-cloud-eureka does it on the dashboard. Also the replica are listed as unavailable.

Comment: I can't see anything in your eureka configuration that would do that. Maybe your proxy is monkeying with the paths? If you think it's something in Spring Cloud, perhaps you could create a minimal sample that reproduces the problem (without the proxy obviously).

Comment: I do not think it is an error in Spring Cloud or Eureka, the question might be if there is some way to make the context path public via Eureka, so that consumer services are aware of it?

Comment: I still don't understand the question. I noticed you have errors in your YAML though (it's colons not equals).

Comment: The equals are, because I copied it from some JVM Parameters. I will try to ask this question more concise. Eureka Clients will register themselves with their hostname and port. These information will resume in `<app>-serverdomain.com:<port>` as the clients address. How can I transmit the proxy's context path `/<app>-<version>` so that consumers of the client are aware of it?

Comment: Normally you do that with the "homePage" "statusPage" and "healthCheck". I see you have 2 out of 3. Maybe you need the other. It depends on the calling applications though, how they use that information.

Comment: Actually I found out that the context-path is taken (Tomcat-like) from the file name and ROOT.war will result in root context path, which in the end did solve the problem. Not sure if i would have gotten it working with the path though. Thanks for your time anyway, Dave!